# Mac Java - Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, macos, applet

Some mac users are reporting this error. What version can I build the applet so that Mac users can use it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have more information about the class and/or Mac OS version at issue?

Comment: Afraid not, the client never told me his version. He said he tried updating java so either he didn't update properly, or the newest Mac version is not new enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) of `javac` to compile the code compatible for a particular version of Java.

Then use the `deployJava.js` script (linked from the [info. page on applets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info)) to check the user has the minimum version.

> What version can I build the applet so that Mac users can use it?

As others have mentioned (/alluded to), Macs might support a variety of Java versions.  Perhaps a more relevant question is this.

*What is the minimum Java version required to run the app.?*

> I believe 1.4 maybe 1.3 is the minimum required. I've been using 1.6 to build it tho.

The cross-compilation options (especially using `-bootclasspath`) should answer that question definitively.

I did not mention the `-bootclasspath` initially since you might have been running a 1.7 SDK that now warns to use it when `-source`/`-target` are specified.  Using the option requires that you have an `rt.jar` (the core J2SE classes) of the relevant version to compile against.  It checks that the classes, methods & attributes in the code actually exist in the supplied RT jar.

So the upshot is that if you have a 1.6 (or latest) compiler and a **JRE** of the relevant target version (for the `rt.jar` as well as run-time testing), it should be possible to compile code compatible for any version.

> If I download 1.4 and build with that, it should work for pretty much everyone?

- It does *not* require a JDK, just a JRE and the right cross-compilation options.
- It is impractical to deliver code to 'everyone'.  Some people (or whoever controls the PC they use) choose not to install Java, to disable it if it comes standard.

Comment: I believe 1.4 maybe 1.3 is the minimum required. I've been using 1.6 to build it tho. If I download 1.4 and build with that, it should work for pretty much everyone?

Answer (score 1):

Check out your JDK or JRE version on the Mac. You are using an older version of JDK or JRE to load a jar file that packaged by a newer version of JDK or JRE than yours.